# Upload profile picture

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I want to allow my user to change their profile picture. I followed Symfony2 documentations, it's working. The problem is, i can't call my form using `{{ form_widget(form.file) }}` but I must use `{{ form_widget(form) }}`. It's annoying because I have other value in the `formBuilder` and I want to be able to custom every fields in my twig.

This is my formType.

```
<?php

namespace L3O1\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProfilePictureFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
                    'required'=>false))
                /*->add('aboutMe', 'textarea', array(
                    'attr'=>array(
                    'rows'=>4,
                    'cols'=>50 ),
                    'required'=>false))*/
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'L3O1\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'l3o1_user_profile';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any error when you try to do `{{ form_widget(form.file) }}`  then share it with us.

If `{{ form_widget(form.file) }}` only doesnt save the file then your problem must be a missing token or missing enctype to the form :

```
<form id="someid" action="{{somepath}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

    {#your codes#}

    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}

</form>
```

Comment: My `{{ form_widget(form.file) }}` upload file and delete the current file. Your solution works, but I don't understand why I need to use token ? Thanks !

Comment: i am not sure if it was either the token or the enctype which was giving you problem, but the token is needed in a form to be valid, if it is enabled in your form, the form_enctype add the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form for the file uploads http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp . you can read about symfonys form tokens just google it :) you can put it  as answered if this works for you , for lost lambs